# How do I exclude specific tags from a function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a function I retrieved, that sets up smooth scrolling across a page. However the function is applying it to ALL tags beginning with a hashtag. I need the function to exclude specific tags that exist within a class.

For example I want all `<a href="#">` and `<a href="#somename">` within the class, `.someclass`, to be excluded from the function below.

```
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: `$('a[href]').filter(function (i,n){ return $(n).prop('href').indexOf('#')==0 ;})`

Comment: `$('.someclass a:not([href="#"]), .someclass a:not(href="#somename")')`? Is this maybe what you're thinking. I'm hesitant to post it as an answer because I'm not sure if that's truly what you want. This retrieves all anchor tags from within an element with class `.someclass` whose `href` value does not begin with `#`...

Comment: Yes, definitely would go with the filter() function you could do some difficult validation easy in there, and caching the jQuery object matching the filter could a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use the `not` `jquery` function. like:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').not(".someclass").click(new function() { /* */ })
```

Alternatively you can also include it on your `selector`'s `not`, like:

```
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#],.someclass)').click(function() { /* */ })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g252a4kp/

Comment: Hm thanks. I tried the first option which did not work. I will double check and try the alternative one you list.

Comment: The second option is not the same as the first. The second selects all anchor tags where the attribute is not equal to `#` and anything with the `.someclass` class. The comma acts as an `or` between the selectors

Comment: @War10ck can you check the jsfiddle attached? thought that is what he wants. ;)

Comment: I see what what you're doing. I interpreted the quesiton slightly differently. Maybe the OP can shed some light on it for us? It sounded like the OP wanted all `a` within `.someclass` that did not contain `[href="#"]` or `[href="#somename"]`. Not sure if this is right though. Can you clarify @rpeg what you're looking for?...